# Python Tkinter in thread or in main app?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Tkinter App which does some long running operation. In order to prevent Tkinter window from hanging, i am introducing threading :- one thread for performing long running operation, second thread will be for updating GUI based on the QUEUE which will be filled by long running operation. Now I am thinking of running Tkinter mainloop in a separate thread instead of main thread, reason being is I want to update the state of GUI (Configure some buttons), only once the long running thread is complete. If I run the Tkinter mainloop in main thread, it won't wait for long running thread to complete and will update the GUI before it. So is it safe if i run Tkinter main loop in separate thread and in main loop wait for long running thread to complete before other updates? Any other ideas for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that tk needs to be run in the main thread.

Comment: I am too in favor of that, but in my problem statement if it run in main thread. How can i control certain updates of GUI which needs to be done only after "long-running thread" is complete. I am thinking of checking status of this thread in second thread ("Thread responsible for updating GUI when data available") and once it is not alive, then to update status of GUI that operation is complete. Is this approach fine or somehow I can assign this responsibility in main thread?

Comment: Your worker thread pushes data to a thread-safe queue or semaphore, and your main GUI thread needs to poll this queue or semaphor on a regular basis.